# Laptop won't work if it is cold or uses too much power

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-management, components

I have a problem that my computer won't even boot if it's not hot enough or if my graphics card is not underclocked.
I decided to check inside for visible broken components, clean dust, replace thermal pastes.
I only found two non-smd capacitors and they looked fine(no bulges) and every other components looked fine except two which I couldn't identify. http://m.imgur.com/sV4LH8C
What are those gray square parts?
I Google'd the writings(R36 I422-01) but couldn't find anything.
Can they cause the problems I described?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
P36      INDUCTOR HIGH CURRENT 0.36UH SMD
IR7932   SWITCHING POWER SUPPLY IC
```

The inductor cannot be the problem but a temperamental switching power supply IC could be very well involved on the problems you describe.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but doesn't IR7932 looks fine? The component I was talkimg about is c R36 I422-01, it's legs looks rusty and leaked.

Comment: I understand but an inductor should not be a problem...

Comment: I do not see any reason to think that anything is visually showing bad there, other than parts like that could have been manually soldered, flux and all, so they might not have the same apperance .   Did you first try a very good quality or better even external power supply , if you think it is a power problem?   What is the Model of the laptop?  How old was it, just how dustry was it?  how crusty was the thermal goop?

Comment: Rest of the parts looks like brand new without any marks so I guessed those are causing the problem. I tried new power brick, replacing power socket on laptop. Computer model is Clevo 870CU and it is about 5 years old, I regularly(every 2 3 months) clean dust and replace pastes. I also removed every part one by one (hdd, disc drive, bluetooth, ram, cpu, gpu) and tried to start it, it always shuts about 1 sec after I press the power button.

Comment: does it work if you underclock your graphic card? if that is the case your card is probably creating an unusual current demand triggering the shutting down of the main switching power supply

Comment: I also thought that, even looked for replacement in Ebay but I decided to remove graphics card and start the computer,it still shuts down before BIOS giving error about no graphics card.

Comment: well , that's a different error that does not rule out you might still have a video issue...you should try "replacing" the video card if possible.